# How to Find a circuit that evolves from one density matrix to another(qiskit or cirq)

Tags: qiskit, density-matrix, cirq

given two density matrices, dmBefore and dmAfter, I want to generate(find) a circuit in Qiskit or Cirq that starting initaliazed with dmBefore ends with dmAfter after it's execution. Is it possible?.

This is because I'm trying to express a 5 qubit circuit with 10 density matrices where each one is from a partial trace of pair of qubits.(0,1) or (0,2) or ...(3,4). This works 1 qubit intructions like h,x ry...by appling the instruction to all Density matrix that have that qubit, but for **CX** it doesn't. I've tried CX with the DM that have control and target and if control is on also apply a X in the DM's that have the target, but it doesn't work. So I thought that maybe qiskit can find the circuits that will transform each DM.

Also, I know that Qiskit have the evolve method for density matrixs witch takes a quantum circuit, but I don't know if Cirq can evolve a density matrix with a quantum circuit.